# missing main.py and GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE not specified in cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to deploy a simple python code on google cloud functions service using pub/sub triggers and scheduler. If I use the inline editor everything would be fine but once I try to upload a simple script I get *missing main.py and GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE not specified in cloud functions* error.

I create a zip file from a main.py file with my script in it and a requirement.txt file with all the libraries I need.

This is my script file and the entry point is main

```
def main(data,context):
    print('This is function')
    print('Done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('data','context')
```

I appreciate if someone can help me with this

I kept simplifying my code so I could see if there are any other issue with the code

Comment: Can you share your file structure, how you deploy and screenshots if you use the UI?